# \hbox plus-minus behaviour

Tags: box, glue

I write `\hbox to 10cm{P\hspace{2cm plus 5mm}Q}`. Why does TeX put 'P' to the left and 'Q' to the very right of the box? I thought the horizontal space was 2cm itself and (2+.5)cm at maximum. Moreover, even if I write `\hbox to 10cm{P Q}`, i.e. without any glue-stretchers, the result will be exactly the same. Where does TeX take so big length to put it between 'P' and 'Q'?

Comment: You have provided only one "space" here for TeX to work with.  Add a single typed space at the beginning and end of the box and see what happens.  (And see my comment on the answer by @DavidCarlisle.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed TeX will stretch any available stretch to achieve the stated size.

As it needs to overstretch this will be an underfull box and TeX reports

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 1
```

As normal inter-word space  is similarly underful.

10000 is an arbitrary maximum and any badness calculated above that is truncated to 10000 but for example

```
\hbox to 10cm{P\hspace{2cm plus 2cm}Q}
```

is

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 5231) detected at line 5
```

and  with

```
\hbox to 10cm{P\hspace{2cm plus 5cm}Q}
```

The badness (which is 334) is below the default `\hbadness` so not reported at all.

Comment: So the matter is in badness. I have just tried to increase the plus-component as you wrote and the badness message disappeared. So TeX takes the necessary length from the plus-value and stretches successfully if the basic length is not enough. Thank you for the answer!@David Carlisle

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that setting something in a box of fixed length will always pay attention to all the spaces in the box -- and there's only one space in the middle here.  Add typed spaces at the ends, and the result will be different: `\hbox to 10cm{ P\hspace{2dm plus 2cm}Q }`

Comment: @Vladimir the exact formula doesn't usually matter (it's in the texbook) but essentially badness is proportional to the cube (third power) of the ratio of the amount the glue had to stretch compared to the amount of stretch specified in the `plus` component.

Comment: So there is a length TeX must stretch/shrink anyway and a length 'allowed' by the plus/minus component. The less 'freedom' TeX has (by plus-minus range) the more badness is. And if TeX actually needs 2cm to stretch but the plus component is 7cm then it is okay? The reverse situation is bad?